# how to change error code for http request in android

Tags: android

this is my http request code to show the text from a text file in textview

```
private TextView txtdata;
final String textSource = "http://orthodoxprayers.yolasite.com/resources/saint_elie_sinelfil.txt";



txtdata = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdata);
    new MyTask().execute();
    URL textUrl;

       try {
        textUrl = new URL(textSource);

        BufferedReader bufferReader 
         = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

        String StringBuffer;
        String stringText = "";
        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
         stringText += StringBuffer;   
        }
        bufferReader.close();

        txtdata.setText(stringText);
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        txtdata.setText(e.toString());   
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        txtdata.setText(e.toString());   
       }

   }

   private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    String textResult;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        URL textUrl;

        try {
         textUrl = new URL(textSource);

         BufferedReader bufferReader 
          = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

         String StringBuffer;
         String stringText = "";
         while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
          stringText += StringBuffer;   
         }
         bufferReader.close();

         textResult = stringText;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         textResult = e.toString();   
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         textResult = e.toString();   
        }

     return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

     txtdata.setText(Html.fromHtml(textResult));
     super.onPostExecute(result);   
    }
```

so when a problem occur this request I don't want to get the http error I just want to get a toast telling "problem with download text"

Answer (score 0):

you should show the error log or other message that point out where the error happend,this too much code ,and dont know where the error is

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

do this in asyntask doinbackground()

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        //int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (30 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        int some_reasonable_timeout = 10;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
        //DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // get the response
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and do this in on postexecute

```
        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
        Log.d("tag","status is"+status.toString());
          if (status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
          {
             //download file (download file in another asyntask or you can use thread here but thread will not notify you ,though asyntask does.)
          }
          else
          {
              //show toast
          }
```